# What is a probe query?

Tags: query, documentation, eventlogfile

Recently, I've found an unknown origin value in ReportEvent logs. The documentation is inexhaustive on the subject.

According to all Salesforce documentations, the ProbeQuery event report type origin correspond to a "report executed from a probe query". However, nowhere is stated what is a probe query in Salesforce.

This question was also asked on [Trailblazer Community](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9064S000000DVlpQAG) and [Salesforce Developer group](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IWbXQAW) with no answers.

Documentation:

- [Platform Events Developer Guide > ReportEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_reportevent.htm)
- [SOAP API Developer Guide > Report Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_report.htm)
- [Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform > Report Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_report.htm)

Comment: I see a support case logged for this scenario which is in progress. I will update this thread as I have more information. Thank you --Salesforce Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the support case I've opened, a probe query is a search query used to retrieve column text values and search terms for text bucketing. It is executed by the user when he or she uses the report builder.